# Liferay - Tomcat doesn't pick WAR from deploy folder

Tags: tomcat, liferay, portlet

I am having difficiulties with creating portlet for Liferay. I have standard installation, where Liferay Portal resides in `liferay_home/bundles` and plugins SDK in `liferay_home/plugins`.

I have placed new portlet app in `liferay_home/plugins/portlets/my-portlet`. From there I run `ant deploy` and I can see WAR file was successfully assembled and was copied to `liferay_home/bundles/deploy`.

However, in the running Liferay Portal instancel I don't see portlet that was just freshly copied to **deploy** folder. So I though I'll check out logs, but `liferay_home/bundles/tomcat-7.0.27/logs` is **empty**.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Liferay observes ${liferay.home}/deploy for changes. If you moved your installation, check if you have ${liferay.home} configured in an unexpected location. This commonly happens with portal-setupwizard.properties.

Also, whatever user tomcat/liferay runs at must have read/write access on the deploy directory as well as tomcat's webapps directory if you use this method of deployment. Especially when you don't run tomcat under your own user, or when you're once ran it as root, this can mess up permissions

Lastly, for completeness, tomcat/liferay must run in order to deploy from ${liferay.home}/deploy to tomcat/webapps.

Comment: Thank you, I had wrong location in portal-setupwizard.properties. Too bad that I was unable to find any reasonable logs about this issue whatsoever.

Comment: The logs typically state which deploy directory Liferay is observing, but it's easy to miss. Good to know that you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

While giving path for liferay.home in portal-setup-wizard.properties I had to **replace single backslash with double backslashes** in windows environment.

Comment: in my case i had to replace backslash to forwardslash